# jQuery deferred requests and promises: how to nest concurrent asyncronous calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

The situation I have is the following:

I need to save an array containing student data.
Each student has two nested arrays of Scores Year 1 and Scores Year 2.

My goal is to save data for each student asynchrously - but before I can finalize this process and show the number of students added, I need to save data for Scores Year 1 and Scores Year 2 for each student. This data is also saved asyncronously.

The problem I have at the moment is that student records are saved while Scores Year 1 and Scores Year 2 are still being processed.
The data for Scores Year 1 and Scores 2 must be saved asynchronously for there is no dependency between them. However by the time I'm ready to display the number of students added, all data should be saved.
I must also say that the Scores Year 1 and Scores Year 2 data are depended on the new student id.

How can I achieve this using jQuery promises? If you run the jsFiddle below you'll see that the number of records entered appears BEFORE the Scores Year data is displayed whilst it should be the other way around. The display of the total number of students entered should be dependent on the completion of the Scores Years tasks. Also, I'm not interested in saving student records synchronously.

Here's the code: (Run code in jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w1pd0cns/3/))

```
function performUpdate() {

    var arr_promises = [];

    var students = [
        {
            id: 1, name: 'John', scoresYear1: [{ subject: 'maths', score: 8 },
               { subject: 'chemistry', score: 7 }], scoresYear2: [{ subject: 'maths', score: 9 }, { subject: 'chemistry', score: 8 }]
        },
        {
            id: 2, name: 'Mary', scoresYear1: [{ subject: 'maths', score: 9 },
               { subject: 'chemistry', score: 8 }], scoresYear2: [{ subject: 'maths', score: 10 }, { subject: 'chemistry', score: 7 }]
        }
    ];

    $.each(students, function (index, student) {

        arr_promises.push(SaveStudent(student));

    });

    $.when.apply($, arr_promises).done(function () {
        var msg = '<p>Total number of students added: ' + arguments.length + '</p>';

        $("div").append(msg);
    });
};

function SaveStudent(student) {

    var dfrd = $.Deferred();

    executeQueryAsync(student,

     function () {

         var arrScoreYears = [];

         // Save scores year 1
         $.each(student.scoresYear1, function (index, score) {
             executeQueryAsync(score,
                 function () {
                     arrScoreYears.push({ status: true });
                 },
                 function (sender, args) {
                     alert('Request failed.');
                 });
         });


         // Save scores year 2
         $.each(student.scoresYear2, function (index, score) {
             executeQueryAsync(score,
                 function () {
                     arrScoreYears.push({ status: true });
                 },
                 function (sender, args) {
                     alert('Request failed.');
                 });
         });


         $.when.apply($, arrScoreYears).done(function () {
             //console.log('added score year 1 - Subject:' + score.subject + ' for student: ' + student.name);

             var msg = '<p>Added Score Years for student: ' + student.name + '</p>';

             $("div").append(msg);

         }).then(function () {
             dfrd.resolve({ status: true });
         });;


     },

    // fail
    function (sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed.');
    });
} // end of SaveStudent


function executeQueryAsync(student, callbackSuccess, callbackFail) {

    //simulate server call

    setTimeout(function () {
        callbackSuccess({ status: true });
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: I am able to understand things up until the myContext.executeQueryAsync line. Is the student id returned from the server upon saving the student?

Comment: Yes. After myContext.executeQueryAsyn is executed you can extract the student id which will be used to add ScoresYear1/2 records. This is shown in line var newid = newStudent.get_id();

Comment: First of all, you want to apply your $.when to the arr_promises array *after* the array has been populated. So the $.when call should not be in the $.each call, but after it.

Comment: Secondly, the arr_promises (when implemented correctly) will tell you only that your students have saved, you will need another array of promises if you want to execute code when all of the year/scores requests have returned.

Comment: Your next major problem is that SaveStudent does not return a promise. This means that `arr_promises` *does not* contain any promises - so `$.when` executes immediately.

Comment: `arr_promises` is an empty array. You need to *return* the `dfrd` deferred from `SaveStudent` in order for it to be appended to the `arr_promises` array. You have the right idea where you are creating another array of deferreds, `arrScoreYears`; unfortunately, this array does not hold deferred objects. You must push deferred objects to this array.

Comment: @76484 I added the return dfrd to SaveStudent function but it makes no difference. Would you mind updating the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w1pd0cns/3/ with your idea? Pershaps another option might be to perform the YearScores updates in the $.each iteration in the performUpdate function. In this scenario I would have to move the $.when.apply back to the loop.

Comment: It *does* make a difference. It's just that there are other errors in the code that need to be changed as well. The problem with `dfrd` is that it is resolved too early. This happens because `arrScoreYears` isn't populated with deferreds. I'll provide an answer below.

Comment: @76484 You're right about the arrScoresYears array. I'm just passing a literal instead of deferred object.

Comment: Passing an array of object literals to `$.when` defeats the purpose of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `$.when` then you must pass it one or more deferred objects - at least if you want *when* to have any meaning. If you are not passing any deferred objects to `$.when` then it will execute immediately. Because `SaveStudent` does not return a value, you are feeding an empty array to `$.when` - so your "Total number of students added:..." message will get appended almost instantly.

(If you don't believe me, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76484/rtdk8ono/)

So SaveStudent needs to return a deferred object:

```
function SaveStudent(student) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    /* other SaveStudent stuff */

    return dfrd;
}
```

Having done that, you found that this change made "no difference". This is correct - almost. This is because `dfrd` is getting resolved almost immediately for basically the same reason as explained above. `dfrd` gets resolved when all of the deferred objects in `arrScoreYears` are resolved, but there are no deferred objects in `arrScoreYears` - so `dfrd` is resolved immediately.

So let's add deferreds to `arrScoreYears`. In the interest of DRYness, I will create a single function to accomplish this so that we don't have rewrite the same code for saving year 1 scores and year 2 scores:

```
var saveYearScores = function (year_scores, deferreds) {
    $.each(year_scores, function (index, score) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        deferreds.push(deferred);     
        executeQueryAsync(score,
            function () {
                deferred.resolve();
             },
             function (sender, args) {
                 deferred.fail();
                 alert('Request failed.');
             });
     });
};
```

Notice that we create a deferred for each year score we are asynchronously saving. I have chosen to pass the array that will contain the deferreds into the function so that it can append the new deferred objects to the array. What is important is that for each call to `SaveStudent`, we have an array of deferred objects, each representing an asynchronous save score call.

Now we can replace those each calls in `SaveStudent` with calls to our new function:

```
saveYearScores(student.scoresYear1, arrScoreYears);
saveYearScores(student.scoresYear2, arrScoreYears);
```

And now the `$.when` call will actually *wait* for our save score calls to finish!

I have updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/76484/w1pd0cns/4/